# petapoco as abstractDao or BaseRepository

Tags: c#, orm, petapoco

I am using petaPoco for the first time and i am trying to create some base class that will be an abstractDao class with eliminate the use of sql text for the excellent petaPoco code.
I came to have trouble in the poco that is based on more then one table.
did any of you had success with such projects ?

Answer (score 0):

This link talks about joins..
http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/111/PetaPoco-Experimental-Multi-Poco-Queries

If you have created your poco (or DAO) and it has all the columns you want then you should be able to pass that poco with a query and have it filled with results.

```
db.Fetch<multiTblPoco>(some query);
```

or similar.